# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView not working on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, textinput, react-native-textinput

#### Problem:

I am using **KeyboardAvoidingView** in ios with `behavior="padding"` but it's not working.
My **screen** has four **text input fields**, which get **hidden** by keyboard as it opens.

#### Code:

Screen:

```
const Screen = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
                <TextInput style={styles.input} />
                <TextInput style={styles.input} />
                <TextInput style={styles.input} />
                <TextInput style={styles.input} />
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};
```

Text input styling:

```
input: {
    height: 100,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 60,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginHorizontal: 30,
},
```

#### Expected behaviour:

**KeyboardAvoidView** should shift all the text input fields up as soon as keyboard opens up.

Comment: try to use this library https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: @AkilaDevinda at the moment I don't want to use any external library for this.

Comment: having the same issue, and react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view doesn't work on typescript